# Change webroot-path of registered letsencrypt cert

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I am new with Let's Encrypt certificate. I registered my domain for a nginx server at **digitalocean.com** following this command

> cd /opt/letsencrypt ./letsencrypt-auto certonly -a webroot
>   --webroot-path=**/usr/share/nginx/html** -d mydomain.com -d www.mydomain.com

and it works fine. Then i have changed my **webroot path** to **/var/www/xxx** for my domain.
Now when i trying to renew my letsencrypt certificate it's getting error.
Then i rollback my webroot path, try again and the renewal works perfectly.
Now my question is how can i change my registered **webroot-path** for Let's Encrypt?

Comment: I wrote a blog post that explains some issues related to this: http://tom.busby.ninja/letsecnrypt-nginx-reverse-proxy-no-downtime/

Answer (score 23):

change it in /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/mydomain.conf

set

```
authenticator = webroot
webroot_path=/var/www/xxx/
```

and key moment that took me several hours to figure out - configure webrooth path with `webroot_path=/var/www/xxx/` not with `webroot-path=/var/www/xxx`, note the underscore

Comment: Look, too, for a `webroot_map` section.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to roll back your webroot path in nginx, just change the webroot value when run let's encrypt script.

`/opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/xxx -d mydomain.com -d www.mydomain.com`

The letsencrypt script requires your webroot because the authentication is based on files that added to your webroot, which should be under `/.well-known/acme-challenge/`, the authentication process including external requests to those files so if the two webroot values doesn't match, you will see an error because the auth server couldn't reach that file. Every time you try to get/renew a cert, just make sure you pass exact the same root value from nginx to let's encrypt.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to change email and others information while running that script with new webroot-path ? I did not try yet because it might occur error on my running site.

Comment: @user2817947 you can change email since it's just for receiving notifications like cert expiration notice. It won't cause you problem.

Comment: @user2817947 and i think unless you restart nginx, changes made to your certs won't affect your running site.